# Disarm Linux Minty 16 password

Tags: password

My nephew had an HP lap top running Minty 16. He died almost two years ago and I still cannot figure out his old password. I am 60 y/o and not familiar with computers. 
Can ya'll explain this to me? I can't update, or install or change OS. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that.

1. If the laptop has CD-Rom, you can try burn live CD of ubuntu, and mount the file system read, write; if no CD-Rom, you can try live USB from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu.
2. Then follow instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery. Although it's ubuntu, it should work for minty as well.

   Here is how you can use the Live CD to change the administrative password on your machine if you have lost/forgot the current password. Please note that you can usually boot into RecoveryMode and run the passwd command directly.

   Boot the Ubuntu Live CD or live USB from step 1.

   Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` at the same time

   `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

   If you created a custom partition layout when installing Ubuntu you have to find your root partition using the fdisk utility. See the section Finding your root partition.

   `sudo chroot /mnt`

You can now use the `passwd` command to reset a password.

Note: In the mount command, `/dev/sda1` will need to be replaced with the partition where the root of the file system resides.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I will try to use one of the CDs that I also received; follow your instructions and see if that works. Namaste